# How to access a CoClass that exposes multiple interfaces through COM InterOp?

Tags: com, com-interop, typelib, midl, tlbimp

I've got a CoClass that is describes as below:

```
[
    uuid(xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx), 
    version(1.0), 
    helpstring("FooBar")
]
coclass FooBar
{
    [default] interface IFoo;
    interface IBar;
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Why does `tlbimp` only expose the `IFoo` interface, while `oleview.exe` shows both interfaces?
2. Does `tlbimp` only expose [`[default]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366787.aspx) interfaces and why? (According to the MSDN `[default]` *"is intended for use by macro languages."*)
3. How can I model this case in MIDL/COM? Should I use association instead of inheritance?

Comment: If you declare your interfaces in either the same idl-file or import the interfaces from another idl-file, your object can expose as many interfaces as desired. After obtaining an object with CoCreateInstance() you need to use QueryInterface() to obtain your desired interface. Have look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680573(VS.85).aspx) and consider the reference, too. And about [MIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367091(v=vs.85).aspx) there are some examples, too.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know that I can access the interfaces through `QueryInterface()`, but my question concerns the RCW's that get generated from `tlbimp` and accessed by .NET clients. I am not able to call `QueryInterface` in .NET 2.0 (I guess it was introduced with .NET 4.0, but this is not an option atm).

Comment: The CLR automatically calls QueryInterface, just cast the object to the interface type.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks! :) But couldn't the InterOp automatically `QueryInterface` whenever I call `IBar.Something()` like `new FooBar().Something()` (without casting it explicitly to IBar)? What I do not understand is why the interop does not inherit the CoClass from all interfaces... this would simplify client development, since I can see all members of all interfaces with IntelliSense. I would accept an answer that substantiates that decision. :)